# The method 'userLogin' isn't defined for the type 'BottomSheet'

Tags: flutter, dart, methods

I have this error in the onPressed :() function of the login: The method 'userLogin' is not defined for the type 'BottomSheet'.
Could anyone help me solve? Thank you.

```
                CustomButton(
                  label: "LOGIN",
                  primaryColor: Theme.of(context).primaryColor,
                  secondaryColor: Colors.white,
                  onPressed: () => {
                  // Validate returns true if the form is valid, or false otherwise.
                  if (_formKey.currentState.validate()) {
                    userLogin()}
                    
                },
                ),
```

Here is the complete code:

```dart
import 'dart:convert';    
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:http/http.dart' as http;
import 'package:login_ui/home2.dart';
import 'clipper.dart';

class Home extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _HomeState createState() => _HomeState();
}

class _HomeState extends State<Home> {
  TextEditingController _emailController,
      _passwordController,
      _nameController = TextEditingController();

//
  bool _visible = false;

  Future userLogin() async {
    //Login API URL
    //use your local IP address instead of localhost or use Web API
    String url = "https://www.toptradeitaly.com/login_api/user_login.php";

    // Showing LinearProgressIndicator.
    setState(() {
      _visible = true;
    });

    // Getting username and password from Controller
    var data = {
      'username': _emailController.text,
      'password': _passwordController.text,
    };

    //Starting Web API Call.
    var response = await http.post(url, body: json.encode(data));
    if (response.statusCode == 200) {
      //Server response into variable
      print(response.body);
      var msg = jsonDecode(response.body);

      //Check Login Status
      if (msg['loginStatus'] == true) {
        setState(() {
          //hide progress indicator
          _visible = false;
        });

        // Navigate to Home Screen
        Navigator.push(
            context,
            MaterialPageRoute(
                builder: (context) =>
                    HomePage(uname: msg['userInfo']['NAME'])));
      } else {
        setState(() {
          //hide progress indicator
          _visible = false;

          //Show Error Message Dialog
          showMessage(msg["message"]);
        });
      }
    } else {
      setState(() {
        //hide progress indicator
        _visible = false;

        //Show Error Message Dialog
        showMessage("Error during connecting to Server.");
      });
    }
  }

  Future<dynamic> showMessage(String _msg) {
    showDialog(
      context: context,
      builder: (BuildContext context) {
        return AlertDialog(
          title: new Text(_msg),
          actions: <Widget>[
            TextButton(
              child: new Text("OK"),
              onPressed: () {
                Navigator.of(context).pop();
              },
            ),
          ],
        );
      },
    );
  }


//

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    //GO logo widget
    Widget logo() {
      return Padding(
        padding:
            EdgeInsets.only(top: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height * 0.15),
        child: Container(
          width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
          height: 220,
          child: Stack(
            children: <Widget>[
              Positioned(
                  child: Container(
                child: Align(
                  child: Container(
                    decoration: BoxDecoration(
                        shape: BoxShape.circle, color: Colors.white),
                    width: 150,
                    height: 150,
                  ),
                ),
                height: 154,
              )),
              Positioned(
                child: Container(
                    height: 154,
                    child: Align(
                      child: Text(
                        "GO",
                        style: TextStyle(
                          fontSize: 120,
                          fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                          color: Theme.of(context).primaryColor,
                        ),
                      ),
                    )),
              ),
              Positioned(
                width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width * 0.15,
                height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width * 0.15,
                bottom: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height * 0.046,
                right: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width * 0.22,
                child: Container(
                  decoration: BoxDecoration(
                      shape: BoxShape.circle, color: Colors.white),
                ),
              ),
              Positioned(
                width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width * 0.08,
                height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width * 0.08,
                bottom: 0,
                right: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width * 0.32,
                child: Container(
                  decoration: BoxDecoration(
                      shape: BoxShape.circle, color: Colors.white),
                ),
              ),
            ],
          ),
        ),
      );
    }

    void _loginSheet(context) {
      showBottomSheet<void>(
        context: context,
        builder: (BuildContext context) {
          return BottomSheet(
            emailController: _emailController,
            passwordController: _passwordController,
          );
        },
      );
    }

    void _registerSheet(context) {
      showBottomSheet<void>(
        context: context,
        builder: (BuildContext context) {
          return BottomSheet(
            emailController: _emailController,
            passwordController: _passwordController,
            nameController: _nameController,
          );
        },
      );
    }

    return Scaffold(
      resizeToAvoidBottomInset: false,
      backgroundColor: Theme.of(context).primaryColor,
      body: Builder(builder: (context) {
        return Column(
          children: <Widget>[
            logo(),
            Padding(
              child: Column(
                crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.stretch,
                children: [
                  CustomButton(
                    label: "LOGIN",
                    primaryColor: Colors.white,
                    secondaryColor: Theme.of(context).primaryColor,
                    onPressed: () => _loginSheet(context),
                  ),
                  SizedBox(height: 20),
                  CustomButton(
                    label: "REGISTER",
                    primaryColor: Theme.of(context).primaryColor,
                    secondaryColor: Colors.white,
                    onPressed: () => _registerSheet(context),
                  ),
                ],
              ),
              padding: EdgeInsets.only(top: 80, left: 20, right: 20),
            ),
            Expanded(
              child: Align(
                child: ClipPath(
                  child: Container(
                    color: Colors.white,
                    height: 300,
                  ),
                  clipper: BottomWaveClipper(),
                ),
                alignment: Alignment.bottomCenter,
              ),
            )
          ],
          crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.stretch,
        );
      }),
    );
  }
}

class CustomButton extends StatelessWidget {
  final Color primaryColor;
  final Color secondaryColor;

  final String label;
  final Function() onPressed;
  const CustomButton({
    Key key,
    this.primaryColor,
    this.secondaryColor,
    @required this.label,
    this.onPressed,
  }) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return SizedBox(
      height: 50,
      width: double.infinity,
      child: RaisedButton(
        highlightElevation: 0.0,
        splashColor: secondaryColor,
        highlightColor: primaryColor,
        elevation: 0.0,
        color: primaryColor,
        shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
            borderRadius: new BorderRadius.circular(30.0),
            side: BorderSide(color: Colors.white, width: 3)),
        child: Text(
          label,
          style: TextStyle(
              fontWeight: FontWeight.bold, color: secondaryColor, fontSize: 20),
        ),
        onPressed: onPressed,
      ),
    );
  }
}

class CustomTextField extends StatelessWidget {
  final Icon icon;
  final String hint;
  final TextEditingController controller;
  final bool obsecure;

  const CustomTextField({
    this.controller,
    this.hint,
    this.icon,
    this.obsecure,
    Key key,
  }) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return TextField(
      controller: controller,
      obscureText: obsecure ?? false,
      style: TextStyle(
        fontSize: 20,
      ),
      decoration: InputDecoration(
          hintStyle: TextStyle(fontWeight: FontWeight.bold, fontSize: 20),
          hintText: hint,
          enabledBorder: OutlineInputBorder(
            borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(30),
            borderSide: BorderSide(
              color: Theme.of(context).primaryColor,
              width: 2,
            ),
          ),
          border: OutlineInputBorder(
            borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(30),
            borderSide: BorderSide(
              color: Theme.of(context).primaryColor,
              width: 3,
            ),
          ),
          prefixIcon: Padding(
            child: IconTheme(
              data: IconThemeData(color: Theme.of(context).primaryColor),
              child: icon,
            ),
            padding: EdgeInsets.only(left: 30, right: 10),
          )),
    );
  }
}
//
  final _formKey = GlobalKey<FormState>();
//
class BottomSheet extends StatelessWidget {
  const BottomSheet({
    Key key,
    @required TextEditingController emailController,
    @required TextEditingController passwordController,
    TextEditingController nameController,
  })  : _emailController = emailController,
        _passwordController = passwordController,
        _nameController = nameController,
        super(key: key);

  final TextEditingController _emailController;
  final TextEditingController _passwordController;
  final TextEditingController _nameController;

  List<Widget> get _registerLogo => [
        Positioned(
          child: Container(
            padding: EdgeInsets.only(bottom: 25, right: 40),
            child: Text(
              "REGI",
              style: TextStyle(
                fontSize: 38,
                fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                color: Colors.white,
              ),
            ),
            alignment: Alignment.center,
          ),
        ),
        Positioned(
          child: Align(
            child: Container(
              padding: EdgeInsets.only(top: 40, left: 28),
              width: 130,
              child: Text(
                "STER",
                style: TextStyle(
                    fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                    color: Colors.white,
                    fontSize: 38),
              ),
            ),
            alignment: Alignment.center,
          ),
        ),
      ];
  List<Widget> get _loginLogo => [
        Align(
          alignment: Alignment.center,
          child: Container(
            child: Text(
              "LOGIN",
              style: TextStyle(
                fontSize: 42,
                fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                color: Colors.white,
              ),
            ),
            alignment: Alignment.center,
          ),
        ),
      ];

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return DecoratedBox(
      decoration: BoxDecoration(color: Theme.of(context).canvasColor),
      child: ClipRRect(
        borderRadius: BorderRadius.only(
            topLeft: Radius.circular(40.0), topRight: Radius.circular(40.0)),
        child: Container(
          child: ListView(
            children: <Widget>[
              Container(
                child: Stack(
                  children: <Widget>[
                    Positioned(
                      left: 10,
                      top: 10,
                      child: IconButton(
                        onPressed: () {
                          Navigator.of(context).pop();
                          _emailController.clear();
                          _passwordController.clear();
                          _nameController?.clear();
                        },
                        icon: Icon(
                          Icons.close,
                          size: 30.0,
                          color: Theme.of(context).primaryColor,
                        ),
                      ),
                    )
                  ],
                ),
                height: 50,
                width: 50,
              ),
              //
           Form(
              key: _formKey,
              child:
              //
              SingleChildScrollView(
                child: Padding(
                  padding: EdgeInsets.only(left: 20, right: 20),
                  child: Column(
                    children: <Widget>[
                      Container(
                        width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
                        height: 140,
                        child: Stack(
                          children: <Widget>[
                            Align(
                              child: Container(
                                width: 130,
                                height: 130,
                                decoration: BoxDecoration(
                                    shape: BoxShape.circle,
                                    color: Theme.of(context).primaryColor),
                              ),
                              alignment: Alignment.center,
                            ),
                            ..._nameController != null
                                ? _registerLogo
                                : _loginLogo
                          ],
                        ),
                      ),
                      SizedBox(height: 60),
                      if (_nameController != null)
                        CustomTextField(
                          controller: _nameController,
                          hint: "NAME",
                          icon: Icon(Icons.person),
                        ),
                      SizedBox(height: 20),
                      CustomTextField(
                        controller: _emailController,
                        hint: "EMAIL",
                        icon: Icon(Icons.email),
                      ),
                      SizedBox(height: 20),
                      CustomTextField(
                        controller: _passwordController,
                        hint: "PASSWORD",
                        icon: Icon(Icons.lock),
                        obsecure: true,
                      ),
                      SizedBox(height: 20),
                      if (_nameController != null)
                        CustomButton(
                          label: "REGISTER",
                          primaryColor: Theme.of(context).primaryColor,
                          secondaryColor: Colors.white,
                          onPressed: () {},
                        ),
                      SizedBox(height: 20),
                      if (_nameController == null)
                        CustomButton(
                          label: "LOGIN",
                          primaryColor: Theme.of(context).primaryColor,
                          secondaryColor: Colors.white,
                          onPressed: () => {
                          // Validate returns true if the form is valid, or false otherwise.
                          if (_formKey.currentState.validate()) {
                            userLogin()}                                
                        },
                        ),
                      SizedBox(height: 20),
                    ],
                  ),
                ),
              ),),
            ],
          ),
          height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height / 1.1,
          width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
          color: Colors.white,
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Can you include more about your widget, seems like you didn't define `userLogin` or it is out of scope/not imported. And you can just use `onPressed: (){ ...}`

Comment: You need to define `userLogin()` within your `BottomSheet()`, currently, it's defined in another class, define it in `BottomSheet()`

Comment: are you using null-safety

Comment: @YeasinSheikh excuse my ignorance (I'm here to learn), but is it a question or a statement? what do you mean "you are using null security" ..

Comment: Are you using flutter null-safety ?  Can you include your flutter version

Comment: @YeasinSheikh Flutter 3.0

Comment: modifying the BottomSheet class so there is no more error:

` class BottomSheet extends StatelessWidget {
const BottomSheet({
 Key key,
 @required TextEditingController emailController,
 ..
 @required this.onSubmit,
  })  : _emailController = emailController,
        ....
    super(key: key);

    final TextEditingController _emailController;
    ...
    final void Function() onSubmit; `

But now when I click on the LOGIN or REGISTER button it doesn't do anything .... What am I wrong again?
Thank you